# SnappyData version 0.6 not found in Maven

Tags: maven, version, snappydata

https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/releases

I apologize in advance if this is the wrong forum to ask this question.

We are interested in version 0.6.  According to the readme, the maven repository should contain the following items:

groupId: io.snappydata
artifactId: snappy-core_2.10
version: 0.6

groupId: io.snappydata
artifactId: snappy-cluster_2.10
version: 0.6

A link to the snappy-core jar is provided on github, but not for the cluster jar.  This is preventing our streaming apps from being built due to scala dependency errors between 0.5 and 0.6.

Can someone please advise? thanks!

Comment: Hi mike, will get this sorted ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artifact ids have changed with 0.6 release, the docs still had old ids.

Please use

> groupId: io.snappydata artifactId: snappydata-core_2.11 version: 0.6
>
> groupId: io.snappydata artifactId: snappydata-cluster_2.11 version: 0.6